# How to use cv2 in flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm new to Flask ,I try to upload image to static folder and use cv2 to make Gaussian image

```
`@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        return "Your image has been save" + myfunction(filename)
    return render_template('upload.html')
`
```

upload is working but when i try to use cv2 to make image this Gaussian blur
error occur

> RuntimeError: cannot access configuration outside request

```
@app.route('/upload/filename')
def myfunction(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    gblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    return render_template('show.html', gblur=gblur)
```

> show.html

```
<body>
    {% if gblur %}
      <h1>Image Gaussian Blur</h1><br>
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', gblur=gblur) }}">
      <br><button><a href="{{ url_for('upload') }}">Go back to Upload New Image</a></button>
    {% else %}
      <h1>no image for whatever reason</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Anyone have any idea? thanks.

Comment: Save the processed image at local, then update the filename in the html.

Comment: thanks, i try to use ` img = cv2.imread(filename)  img1=imwrite("gblur.jpg",img)` but  it creates a result image with 0 kb size
Can you help me more?

Comment: Check the `img`, make sure it's not None or empty :`print(img.shape)`. And take care of your directory path.